# docker systemD stuck at activating (start) on kali

Tags: docker, systemd

Service stuck on activating (start) and never starts

```
Jan 02 08:35:49 kail dockerd[1337]: time="2021-01-02T08:35:49.254338338Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jan 02 08:35:59 kail dockerd[1337]: time="2021-01-02T08:35:59.327638653Z" level=info msg="Container f34db773beee2371244dbcf3d75ded7fed932b2eed8d038b0f8113ab6a19e0ea failed to exit within 10 seconds of signal 15 - using the force"
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

resolved by deleting the container from the system

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker/containers/<container>
```

Comment: In hindsight, there would be great to see a detailed "post-mortem". Got the same issue recently, but it was after no effective change in my workflow. What caused your container to fail and hang?